# Ubuntu switching between monitor settings while booting

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, system-settings, external-monitor

I have connected my laptop to an external monitor via a VGA cable and set up the system to use only the external one (`Single Display` setting) but I have some problems at the boot. When I boot the PC it switches from one monitor setting to another:

1. At first, while the BIOS loads, the native screen is the only one to be used (`Single Display` on native monitor)
2. The screen asking for the cryptsetup is shown on both the monitors (`Mirror`)
3. The boot is shown on both the monitors (`Mirror`)
4. The login screen appears only on the native monitor while the external one shows a violet background (`Join Displays`)
5. When I log in the native screen is switched off and the external one is the only used (`Single Display` on the external monitor)

I suppose that until I have not logged in Ubuntu ignores my personal settings and uses some default ones, which is good for safety but causes me some trouble. Is there a way to change those default settings to be able to log in from the external monitor?

I have no idea about what information could be useful to solve the problem, please ask in the comments what is needed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It _nearly_ does. Now the login screen is shown only on the external monitor, but: 1-the boot and shutdown processes are still shown on both the monitors (in `Mirror` mode); 2-when I log in, for some moments the external monitor is turned off before Ubuntu turns it on again and turns off the native one. Those are more nuisances than real problems but they quite bother me.

Comment: My screens rest during boot too. I think it is caused by one process taking over from another. I don't think there is much one can do about this.